# li background hover change background

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-image

I am trying two create a rollover effect on my `<li>` with the background of the `<li>` Changing completely. The background on the none active state fits close but on rollover the background is off. below is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebox">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://2020mediaonline.com/wptest/wp-login.php">Log in</a></li>
<li><a href="http://2020mediaonline.com/wptest/?feed=rss2">Entries</a></li>
<li><a href="http://2020mediaonline.com/wptest/?feed=comments-rss2" >Comments</a></li>
<li><a href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
div.sidebox ul {list-style-type:none;font:12px arial;}
div.sidebox ul li{background: url(images/right_ul_bg.jpg) no-repeat left;padding:10px 0 0 50px;}
div.sidebox ul li a{text-decoration:none;color:white;display:block;height:31px; width:247px;}
div.sidebox ul li a:hover{ background:#2f373c url(images/right_ul_bg_hover.jpg) -10px -50px;}
```

here is a live example http://jsfiddle.net/cd7rR/

Comment: have you checked in firebug that the image is loading or not

Comment: Both images load one on hover the other when the page loads but the hover image is offset a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the hover background image on the *anchor*. The original background image is on the *list-item*. The *anchor* is offset because you have padding declared on the *list-item*. Here's a demo with the hover background on the *list-item*.

```
div.sidebox ul li:hover{ background:url(http://2020mediaonline.com/wptest/wp-content/themes/Price_LawTheme/images//right_ul_bg_hover.jpg) no-repeat;}div.sidebox ul
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cd7rR/1/

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help and thanks for helping me understand my issue. +1 and checked.